# Proj executable PROJ_DIR not found when pip installing floris local editable installation

Tags: python, pip, installation, conda, floris

When trying to install floris local editable installation using pip and the most recent github repo (develop branch) I get the following error:

```
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\nilsg\Miniconda3\envs\florisEnv\python.exe' 'C:\Users\nilsg\Miniconda3\envs\florisEnv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\nilsg\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpl5e1fb4s'
       cwd: C:\Users\nilsg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h135k_66\pyproj
  Complete output (1 lines):
  Proj executable not found. Please set PROJ_DIR variable.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\nilsg\Miniconda3\envs\florisEnv\python.exe' 'C:\Users\nilsg\Miniconda3\envs\florisEnv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\nilsg\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpl5e1fb4s' Check the logs for full command output.
```

So far I have tried clearing the cache, reinstalling pyproj and reinstalling Miniconda with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can do an editable pip install under conda. An alternative is to use conda-build and conda-develop: `conda develop floris/`.

This article doesn't address this problem specifically, but you should be aware of potential problems when mixing both: https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have sorted this now but it was certainly not easy. I am starting to think it would be a lot easier just to use Python and virtualenv, is that what you use?

Comment: Yes, thats what I've been using for FLORIS for the past couple of years. However, conda seems to be the default in scientific software so I've recently been trying to force myself to move to that. Within my conda environments, I try to avoid using pip at all cost.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I had trouble getting some of the packages through conda and ended up having to clone the GitHub repos and build/develop them from my local drive, which doesn't seem a very tidy way to do it, especially given my `pip list` and `conda list` commands now give different results. 
I don't suppose there's any way to add GitHub as a conda channel? Just for reference, I had to do this with h5pyd and floris itself, naturally.